# Create Unlocked Packages without using Salesforce DX?

Tags: unlocked-package

Is there any way to create an unlocked package from salesforce ui instead of having to use Salesforce DX?

Thanks,
Asif K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DX is required to create new packages and package versions. The underlying API is not documented and subject to change at any time, so by providing a CLI, salesforce.com has provided a consistent interface for us to use while being able to quickly iterate new features and enhancements, which are pretty much happening every few weeks to months. This also allows them to deploy new versions asynchronously to Salesforce releases.

If you want to, though, you can create a normal package in the package manager (an unmanaged package), and then use force:source:retrieve or force:mdapi:retrieve followed by force:mdapi:convert commands to easily convert your unmanaged package to an unlocked package.

Note: This answer is not suggesting that the ability to edit these packages in the UI will never be possible, just that it is limited right now, and there are no publicly known designs to provide such an interface, so all we have to go on right now is the current state of technology.

Comment: @sfdxfox, if you could elaborate on how to convert an unmanaged package to an unlocked package that would be of great help to us.. Thanks..

Comment: @Suha It's basically as simple as `sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Package Name"` ... `sfdx force:package:create -t Unlocked -n "Package Name"` ... `sfdx force:package:version:create -n "Package Name"` ... Read the docs for the available parameters, though, and you'll need to satisfy any feature dependencies (e.g. enabling communities) in a config file. The overall process is relatively painless, though.